# FAQ for authorship standards

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

This is inspired by: [Can PhD students publish papers as sole author without including their supervisor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98392/can-phd-students-publish-papers-as-sole-author-without-including-their-superviso)

Authorship standards come up often, and I think there are at least two issues which are commonly re-iterated on these posts, and could use a standard answer or FAQ entry. These are:

- There are established professional standards for authorship, at least in some fields, e.g. [ICMJE standards](http://www.icmje.org/recommendations/browse/roles-and-responsibilities/defining-the-role-of-authors-and-contributors.html). (Perhaps a list here would be appropriate)
- New graduate students often under-estimate the work required to choose a problem and set the group's general research direction, which can qualify an advisor for authorship even if they do not perform the research.

Is it worth creating a FAQ with information like this, or should we just point people at questions like: [What are the minimum contributions required for co-authorship](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12030/what-are-the-minimum-contributions-required-for-co-authorship) ? If so, what else should be there?

Comment: I think what you want is a canonical question on the main site, not a FAQ on Meta.